# Spring @ transactional, how to configure two different nodes of data base

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

I want to configure @transactional annotations with two different database nodes.

If one database nodes is failing, then transaction manager should work with the second node with out any fail.

If the database node is failing in between a transaction then aslo it should work with second node .is there any way to configure this in spring

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt multitenancy approach in your case

See https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation

You need to override MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl methods

```
public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier)
public Connection getAnyConnection()
```

To check and return the second DataSource connection if the first fails.

Not a simple task though.

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer is already provided above, I am posting it again with more details,

I agree that You can use `MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl` along with `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`, I have implemented both long back and I am posting my code for more help.

The purpose of both is to be understood first.

`CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` is used for the purpose of identifying which connection is to be used for given tenant and for this you would need a tenant identification. For the logic of tenant identification, you can override this. In your case, it will be fixed i.e. you will always point to your first database.

```
public class TenantIdentifierAndSchemaResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    private String tenantIdentifier = "FIRST_DATABASE";

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return this.tenantIdentifier;
    }

    /**
     * Reason why it retuns a false is because we don't want to validate the
     * tenant identifier in the current session.
     * 
     * Please read below.
     * {@link CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver#validateExistingCurrentSessions()}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return false;
    }

    public void setTenantIdentifier(String tenantIdentifier) {
        this.tenantIdentifier = tenantIdentifier;
    }
}
```

After this, you need to implement the `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` using which you will actually switch the database for the incoming request.

```
public class CustomMultiTenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9033113494774715973L;

    private Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CustomMultiTenantConnectionProvider.class);

    private BasicDataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Fetching any connection >");
        }
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        Connection tenantSpecificConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(tenantIdentifier)) {
        Statement statement = tenantSpecificConnection.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery("use " + tenantIdentifier);
        statement.close();
        tenantSpecificConnection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
    } else {
        tenantSpecificConnection.setSchema(Constants.SOMEOTHER_DB);
    }
    return tenantSpecificConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Releasing connection obtained by : getAnyConnection", connection);
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Releasing connection for : {}", tenantIdentifier);
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    /**
     * does the connection provider has support for releasing connection and get
     * back the connection as and when needed ?
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You need to declare these beans in spring configuration and also specify this in hibernate configuration.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.opensource.example" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value-ref="multitenantSchemaResolverAndTenantIdentifier"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"
                    value-ref="multitenantConnectionProvider"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I hope this helps.